# I want to list out sheet names in excel based on a criteria - no macro/vba

Tags: excel, excel-formula, array-formulas

I have an excel document with a couple of sheets. The sheets has a  certain field (cell a1) that contains information about a location. Can be either USA, Asia or Europe. I have listed out the sheets titles in cell p1-p50.

On the main sheet where I would like to list out the sheet names I have a dropdown list in cell a1. According to what I choose there I want to list the sheet names (that match the criteria) in column B.

**I cannot use macros or vba because it has to work in a shared folder online.**

So far I tried the following formula that only works if there is only one sheet name and its located in p1: `=IF(INDEX(INDIRECT("'"&P1&"'!A1"),1)=A1, P1, "")`

If there are 50 from p1:p50 i tried the following but its not working:

```
=IFERROR(TEXTJOIN(";", TRUE, IF(INDEX(INDIRECT("'"&$P$1:$P$50&"'!A1"),1)=A1, $P$1:$P$50, "")), "")
```

Comment: Please, add input example easy to reproduce and expected output